# How to find co-ordinates of lowest pixel in thresholded image?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, image-thresholding

I am new to Python and to coding. I have a .fits image that contains pixels with a range of values. I want to find the pixel in this image that follow the requirements:

1) Value of pixel is above threshold value of 6900.

2) If (1) is met, pixel has the lowest possible y co-ordinates.

That is, if I find that my image has 100 pixels with value > 6900, I wish to find the pixel within those 100 that appears closest to the bottom of the image.

I have achieved the first part by adding a thresholding rule that I have included below:

```
#open .fits file
hdulist = fits.open(f, ignore_missing_end=True)    
hdulist.info()

#close file and save data as numpy array
scidata = hdulist[0].data
hdulist.close()
img = np.array(scidata)

#determine threshold value and apply thresholding to image
threshold = 6900
test = np.greater_equal(img, threshold)  
np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(test))  

#plot image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='magma')
plt.show()
```

However, I am having difficulty in achieving (2). Is there a command in numpy that identifies the smallest possible y co-ordinates of pixels above a certain value threshold?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can try transposing numpy array, casting it all to a list of lists, and then iterate across each column calling `col_list.index(value)` on the min value after threshholding.

Comment: 1.Question: do you have `nan' in you array? One line indicates this, but this line does not get rid of the `nan`s.
2. What is the shape of `img`? I assume it's two dimensional. If so, the minimum might not be defined. Do you want the minimum for each different x value, or do you want all minima having the same (minimal) y value?

Comment: 1. I don't have `nan` values in my array - I thought the line `np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(test))` would set as `nan` all the pixels below the threshold value, although if I have already defined `test` as a threshold test that line may not be useful.

Comment: 2. Yes, `img` is a 2D array of long numbers, (70L, 100L). I suppose I want the minimum for each x value. As I understand it, I have an array of 70x by 100y pixels, each with an intrinsic value associated with a brightness/intensity. I want to find the pixel with lowest value in y that has intrinsic value greater than threshold (6900).

Answer (score 0):

You could find all indices with value above the threshold, then sort these and return the minimal one

```
import numpy as np

# Generate random data
img = 10000 * np.random.rand(10, 10)

# Find indices where the condition is met
indices = np.where(img > 6900)

# sort by y first then x
sorted_indices = sorted((tpl for tpl in zip(*indices)), 
                        key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

result = sorted_indices[0]
```